# Regex stringr to get letter next to a number

Tags: regex, r

In R, I would like to use a `grep` or 'grepl' or 'gsub' command to find all elements in the vector of strings, that have either an A road or M road or a B road name in it..

Please see example below

```
tmp <- c('Little Street','A323', 'Essex Road (A43)', 'M43','Orange street','M4','B2045','New Street')
```

And I would like a function to return...

```
c('Minor Road','A Road', 'A Road', 'M Road', 'Minor Road', 'M Road','B Road','Minor Road')
```

My first thought was to use something like

```
grepl('[0-9]',tmp)
```

but this can't distinguish between the A road, B road and M road....

As always any help would be greatly be appreciated...

Comment: I don't see the connection between your input and expected output. I mean how do you get `Minor Road` without it even being in the input? Well maybe that's because I've never worked with R...

Comment: Minor road is anything that isnt an A road, B road or M road

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this

```
tmp <- c('Little Street','A323', 'Essex Road (A43)', 'M43','Orange street','M4','B2045','New Street')

road <- rep("Minor", length(tmp))
m <- regexpr("\\b[ABM]\\d+", tmp)
road[m!=-1] <- substr(regmatches(tmp, m),1,1)
paste(road, "Road")
```

We use `regmatches()` and `regexpr()` to find and extract A,B, or M followed by one more more letters

Answer (score 3):

You could break it down into steps using `grepl` and `sub` ...

```
> tmp[!grepl('[ABM]\\d', tmp)] <- 'Minor Road'
> sub('.*([ABM])\\d.*', '\\1 Road', tmp)
# [1] "Minor Road" "A Road"     "A Road"     "M Road"     "Minor Road"
# [6] "M Road"     "B Road"     "Minor Road"
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single strapply statement which returns letter followed by `" Road"` for each input component having a letter followed by a number.  For any non-matched components use `"Minor Road"`:

```
library(gsubfn)

strapply(tmp, "(\\D)\\d", ~ paste(x, "Road"), empty = "Minor Road", simplify = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
[1] "Minor Road" "A Road"     "A Road"     "M Road"     "Minor Road"
[6] "M Road"     "B Road"     "Minor Road"
```

**Update:** Simplified answer down to one statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

```
tmp <- c('Little Street','A323', 'Essex Road (A43)', 'M43','Orange street','M4','B2045','New Street')

library(rex)
classify_road <- function(x) {
  res <- re_matches(x,
    rex(
      capture(name = "type",
        upper
      ),
      digit
    )
  )

  res$type[ is.na(res$type) ] <- "Minor"
  paste(res$type, "Road")
}

classify_road(tmp)
#>[1] "Minor Road" "A Road"     "A Road"     "M Road"     "Minor Road"
#>[6] "M Road"     "B Road"     "Minor Road"
```